# Dynamically pass table header in json format bootstrap datatable

Tags: php, json

I am creating data table from json data. Table data is getting fine. Now I want to pass table header with these json data.

my data.php

```
<?php
include('config/db_i.php');
$sql_sel = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `tbl`");
$array = array();
$array['data'] = array();

while($res_sel = mysqli_fetch_row($sql_sel)){
    $array['data'][] = $res_sel;
}
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Now output coming like

```
{"data":[["1","John","USA"],["2","BOB","INDIA"],["3","James","UK"],["4","Dani","CHINA"]]}
```

I want to transfer columns values too...ie, ID,name,Country

Comment: Completely irrelevant, but if your `data.php` contains only PHP code (ie. no HTML chunks between `<?php … ?>`, you should omit the `?>` part to avoid additional blank lines at the end of your file (which can cause problems in some scenarios. Not in this one, though…) Sorry for the noise :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch an associative array from the database with `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysqli_fetch_row()`. Then you will receive a JSON object with the property being the column name, instead of an array. Also I'd suggest using the [`JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` option](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) to ensure numbers are passed as such.

```
<?php
include("config/db_i.php");
$array = array("data"=>array());
$sql_sel = $con->query("SELECT * FROM tbl");
if ($sql_sel) {    
    while($res_sel = $sql_sel->fetch_assoc()){
        $array['data'][] = $res_sel;
    }
}

header("Content-Type:application/json");
echo json_encode($array, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

This should result in something like this:

```
{"data":[{"id":1,"name":"John","country":"USA"},{"id":2,"name":"BOB","country":"INDIA"},{"id":3,"name":"James","country":"UK"},{"id":4,"name":"Dani","country":"CHINA"}]}
```